# Is there a way in R to generate multiple line graph plots with several dataframes

Tags: r, linux

I am hoping to find a way in R where I can generate multiple line graphs plots in a loop. I have an example of the graph that I want in the image below. Both plots belong to one sample. The data structure is the following:

Sample_1_3pGtoA_freq.txt

pos     3pG>A

1       0.226750861079219

2      0.0849366494603472

3       0.0446511627906977

4       0.042654028436019

Sample_1_5pCtoT_freq.txt

pos     5pC>T

1       0.117354740061162

2       0.0789728682170543

3       0.0454746136865342

4       0.0458295142071494

Although it isn't ideal, I would also be happy if I could have just one plot with multiple lines; each line would correspond to the sample number. In this instance, all the 3p lines would be in one plot and all the 5p lines in the other. I am happy to restructure the data in either r or linux. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

[Graph for 1 sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfzqI.png)

Comment: You need to present your data in reproducible format using `dput()`. It is not clear if you want one graph with multiple lines, multiple graphs with one line each, or multiple graphs with multiple lines. Show the code you used to produce the graph in your illustration.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to use dput() on the web browser. The dataformat consists of two columns. The first column is a number and the second number is a a decimal. I am hoping to generate one graph with multiple lines. Here is the code that I used in R to generate it:

Comment: plot1<-ggplot() + geom_line(data=data, aes(x=data$pos, y=data$X5pC.T, color="5 prime")) +

  xlab("Position") +
  
  ylab("Misincorporation frequency") +
  
  scale_colour_manual("", breaks = c("5 prime"), values = c("red")) +
  
  labs(title="A20317 - Anaerolineacae oral taxon 439")+
  
  theme_minimal()+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.35))+
  
  theme(legend.position=c(.6, .75),text=element_text(size=14, family = "TT Times New Roman"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

Comment: plot2<- ggplot() + geom_line(data=data2, aes(x=data2$pos, y=data2$X3pG.A, color="3 prime")) +
  
  xlab("Position") +
  
  ylab("Misincorporation frequency") +
  
  scale_colour_manual("", breaks = c("3 prime"), values = c("blue")) +
  
  theme_minimal()+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.35))+
  
  theme(legend.position=c(.6, .75),text=element_text(size=14, family = "TT Times New Roman"),
  panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
  axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +

  xlim(rev(range(data2$pos)))

Comment: ggarrange(plot1, plot2,
          labels = c("A", "B"),
          ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

Comment: Put this code in your question, not in a series of comments. The `dput()` function produces a version of your data that is easy to copy/paste into your question.